# Annotating the `Self` type in a `TypedDict` with the Alternative Syntax

Tags: python, python-typing, typeddict

I have a `TypedDict` which I am using to represent a query. This query is recursive, so one of the keys can contain the same type as the parent. If I use the `Self` type, it looks like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Self, Iterable

class Query(TypedDict):
    and_: Iterable[Self]
    or_: Iterable[Self]
```

However, I don't want to have this underscore after `and_`: the real key should just be `and`. So then I have to represent this using the function call syntax, since `and` is not a valid identifier in Python:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Self, Iterable

Query = TypedDict("Query", {
    "and": Iterable[Self]
    "or": Iterable[Self]
}
```

Except that `Self` is not valid outside of a class context, so now mypy gives me:

```
test.py:4: error: Variable "typing_extensions.Self" is not valid as a type
```

Now, I could also try the old fashioned way of writing `Self`, [as described here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#motivation). However this method relies on being able to annotate the type of `self` with a `TypeVar`:

```py
TShape = TypeVar("TShape", bound="Shape")

class Shape:
    def set_scale(self: TShape, scale: float) -> TShape:
        self.scale = scale
        return self
```

Unfortunately I can't do this here either, since I'm not using a class.

Lastly, it might seem like I could make my `TypedDict` generic, like this:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias, TypedDict, Self
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Query")

Query = TypedDict("Query", {
    "and": T,
    "or": T
})
```

But again, because I'm not using a class, mypy complains:

```
test.py:7: error: Type variable "test.T" is unbound
test.py:7: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
test.py:7: note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
```

Is there any way to refer to the `Self` type when using the non-class syntax for `TypedDict`?

Comment: What's the base case for a query? (There must be some query that's not a conjunction or disjunction of other queries, other than `{'and': [], 'or': []}`.)

Comment: This looks like something that would require [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/), which is currently under consideration.

Comment: Another option would be to abandon `and` and `or` (which are names of operations) in favor of `conjunction` and `disjunction` (which are the correct terms for these kinds of composite queries), which allows you to retain the declarative syntax that allows `Self`.

Comment: There are other fields that define the actual query, but I've omitted them for concision.

Comment: I could rename the fields, but at that point I might as well just use `and_` which is at least shorter and probably more widely understood.

Comment: Could you mail it to [typing-sig](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/typing-sig@python.org/)? Seems that this concern was simply forgotten when PEP673 was under discussion, this looks like real misbehavior for me.